# Assert a method was called for an object passed as a parameter to a function

Tags: python, unit-testing

```
class Helper:
    def upload_file(self, file_name):
        # some uploading logic here


def process_message(message, helper):
    if "file" in message:
        helper.upload_file(message["file"])
```

Let's say I want to unit test the function process_message. Since there is no real return value to assert against, I would like to assert that helper.upload_file() within process_message was called with 'xyz' file name. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to approach this?

Comment: Pass in a test double?

Comment: The way you would normally handle this is by replacing `helper` with a `mock.Mock` object, and then using the `assert_called_with` method. There's not enough of your code here for me to tell if that's an appropriate solution or not.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you for the help. Ill post an example as an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock

class TestProcessMessage(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_process_message():
        mock_helper = Mock()
        process_message({"file": "my_file_name.csv"}, mock_helper)
        mock_helper.upload_file.assert_called_once_with("my_file_name.csv")
```